# How to change the default normalization for NDEigensystem?

Tags: differential-equations, numerical-integration, physics, finite-element-method, eigenvalues

I'm currently using NDEigensystem to solve a PDE that describes a particle travelling on a hyperbolic (negatively curved) surface. However, the eigenfunctions that are returned by NDEigensystem are not what I'm expecting and I firmly believe this is due to the default normalization that NDEigensystem uses.

According to the documentation, NDEigensystem approximately returns eigenfunctions $\psi(x,y)$ that  satisfy the condition $$\int_D \psi^* \psi \ dxdy = 1$$ (D denotes the region where the eigenfunction lives). However, on this curved surface, the way that I'm looking to normalize the eigenfunction is through the condition $$\int_D \psi^* \psi \frac{1}{y^2} dx dy$$

How can I implement this condition into NDEigensystem? Reading through the documentation ([documentation](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NDEigensystem.html#1413976953)), I'm a little confused about the use of system matrices and the damping/stiffness parameters.

For reference, this is the code I'm currently using (*keyhole* basically defines the domain I'm working in and *test* is the actual PDE that I'm solving).

```
ymax = 100;
numVals = 300;
keyhole = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0, ymax}}];
test = NDEigensystem[{-y^2 (D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]), 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -1/2, 
     TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]], 
    PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1, 
     Function[x, {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}.x]]}, 
   u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, numVals, 
   Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
       "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 0.1}}}];
```

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2):

I am not 100% sure this is correct, but perhaps like this:

```
ymax = 100;
numVals = 3;
keyhole = 
  ImplicitRegion[x^2 + y^2 >= 1, {{x, -1/2, 1/2}, {y, 0, ymax}}];
test = NDEigensystem[{-y^2 (D[u[x, y], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y], {y, 2}]), 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x == -1/2, 
    TranslationTransform[{1, 0}]], 
   PeriodicBoundaryCondition[u[x, y], x^2 + y^2 == 1, 
    Function[x, {{-1, 0}, {0, 1}}.x]]}, 
  u[x, y], {x, y} \[Element] keyhole, numVals, 
  Method -> {"PDEDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement", 
      "MeshOptions" -> {"MaxCellMeasure" -> 1}},
    "VectorNormalization" -> 
     Function[{values, vectors, stiffness, damping},
      s = stiffness; d = damping;
      norm = 
       vectors/(Diagonal[
            vectors.damping.ConjugateTranspose[vectors]]^(1/2) * 
          NIntegrate[1/y^2, {x, y} \[Element] keyhole])]
    }]
```

I'd very useful if you can create a simpler example to test this.